# DAX query for status on a last day

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table as below:

```
> Datestamp             status 

> 01/05/2018, 02:00 AM  success
> 01/05/2018, 04:00 AM  success
> 02/05/2018, 02:00 AM  success
> 02/05/2018, 04:00 AM  fail
> 02/05/2018, 06:00 AM  success
```

I want to have a time which can display status as the success, fail for the last day
if all status is the success for last day, it should show as the success, and if any status for the last day is failing then it should display as fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood you correctly. This maesure will only return success when all of the entries for the last day have a status of 'success'. If one or more of the last day entries have a status of 'fail', the maesure will return 'fail'.

```
[Result] :=
VAR latestDate = INT(MAX('Table'[Datestamp]))
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER ( 'Table', [Status] = "fail" && 'Table'[Datestamp] >= latestDate )
        )
            > 0,
        "fail",
        "success"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, it helped me to get few more ideas :)